# Aggregating into a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following Spark SQL data frame (i.e., `org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`):

```
 type   individual
 =================
 cat    fritz
 cat    felix
 mouse  mickey
 mouse  minnie
 rabbit bugs
 duck   donald
 duck   daffy
 cat    sylvester
```

I want to transform this into a dataframe like this:

```
 type   individuals
 ================================
 cat    [fritz, felix, sylvester]
 mouse  [mickey, minnie]
 rabbit [bugs]
 duck   [donald, daffy]
```

I know that I have to do something like:

```
 myDataFrame.groupBy("type").agg(???)
```

What is the "???"?  Is it something simple?  Or is something as complicated as extending `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate using `collect_list` as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("cat", "fritz"),
  ("cat", "felix"),
  ("mouse", "mickey"),
  ("mouse", "minnie"),
  ("rabbit", "bugs"),
  ("duck", "donald"),
  ("duck", "daffy"),
  ("cat", "sylvester")
).toDF(
  "type", "individual"
)

// Aggregate grouped individuals into arrays
val groupedDF = df.groupBy($"type").agg(collect_list($"individual").as("individuals"))

groupedDF.show(truncate=false)
+------+-------------------------+
|type  |individuals              |
+------+-------------------------+
|cat   |[fritz, felix, sylvester]|
|duck  |[donald, daffy]          |
|rabbit|[bugs]                   |
|mouse |[mickey, minnie]         |
+------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything special to import `collect_list`?

Comment: I'm getting a compilation error:

[error] /Users/paulreiners/dev/ocean-schedules-prediction/src/main/scala/com/transvoyant/VesselSchedules.scala:48: not found: value collect_list
[error]     val groupedDF = sortedData.groupBy($"type").agg(collect_list($"individual").as("individuals"))

Comment: To make various functions including `collect_list` available for your application, you can `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._`.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont mind using a little hql inside, you can go for the collect_list function https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions%28UDAF%29

for example: `sparkContext.sql("select type, collect_list(individuals) as individuals from myDf group by type")`

not sure if you can access it directly in spark though.